# chart.js number of labels equal to number of datapoints

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is probably a really easy question but I just started using javascript a couple of weeks ago and haven't really gotten a good hang of it yet.

I am generating a line chart using chart.js and the array containing the datasets data has a variable length depending on users input. 
I can't get the number of labels to equal the number of data points, so if the array has a lenght of 10, it only has 10 point on the chart instead of 15 or whatever number I hardcodeded into the "labels:" attribute

[image: should stop at 10]

```
var count = dataArray.length; 
var labelnames = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th"];
```

So here if dataArray has length of 10 I would want a string with 10 labels like this one:

```
var labelsOnChart =  ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"];
```

To place on my chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Moreover interesting library 'Chart.js'. Even i am also working on same from past 2 months.

**Solution**

For this you need to create a predefined array which will be global.

```
var labelnames = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", .....];
```

When ever you want your chart specific dataarrayset then do following

```
var count = dataArray.length; 
var requiredLabels = labelnames .slice(0,count);
```

Hope this will solve your problem!!